# Creating distributed dask arrays

Tags: python, distributed, dask

I'm interested in making a distributed dask array out of a bunch of netcdf files I have lying around. I started down the path outlined in ["Distributed Dask arrays"](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2016/02/26/dask-distributed-part-3) but have gotten a little caught up by the deprecation of 'distributed.collections'

What is the best way to create a distributed dask array now? I have my dask-scheduler and dask-worker tasks running. And I can successfully execute the following:

```
from distributed import Client, progress
client = Client('scheduler-address:8786')
futures = client.map(load_netcdf, filenames)
progress(futures)
```

What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use XArray

First, if you have many NetCDF files, then you should take a long look at the XArray package, which wraps Dask.array and manages all of the NetCDF metadata conventions.

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/

In particular I think that you want the [open_mfdataset](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html) function.

#### By Hand

If you want to build a dask.array by hand using techniques in that blogpost then you should use the [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) interface and the [da.from_delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.from_delayed) function.

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#using-dask-delayed

If you want to use Futures as in that blogpost that's fine, `da.from_delayed` will accept Futures in place of delayed values.

```
array_chunks = [da.from_delayed(future, shape=..., dtype=...) 
                for future in futures]
array = da.concatenate(array_chunks, axis=0)
```

Comment: do i still need to launch dask-scheduler and dask-workers to get XArray to leverage dask? reading through http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html doesn't make this exactly clear in my mind.

Comment: There is no difference in startup between XArray and Dask.  You can use the dask.distributed scheduler or the single-machine schedulers.   http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html